# Syntax for changing a python script from sqlite3 to mysql

Tags: python, mysql-python

I have a working python script which retrieves data from a sqlite3 db. I need to convert it to talk to a mysql db though, and here's the first line that is giving me grief:

```
PRODUCT_CODE_ID = "SELECT id FROM localsite_productcode WHERE localsite_productcode.product_code=?"
cur.execute(PRODUCT_CODE_ID,(product_code,))
```

When I try that with mysql I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "gen-csv.py", line 85, in <module>
    cur.execute(PRODUCT_CODE_ID,(product_code,))
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 151, in execute
    query = query % db.literal(args)
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think the DB API for MySQL supports the `?` as a place holder - just try `%s` instead.

Comment: See also [this example](http://mysql-python.sourceforge.net/MySQLdb.html#some-examples) for an explanation.

Comment: Thanks - using %s works, but how does one prevent sql-injection without the ? method?

Comment: @user1294974 It's the same - place holders are normally `:0`, `%s` or `?` - they all do the same thing - remember that `%s` isn't for string interpolation rather than query parameter replacement. In short - just use it and you don't have to worry about it.

Comment: The `db.literal` function, that you see in the exception output, basically goes through all arguments and makes sure that they are properly inserted. This is also what the documentation means with converstion “to a SQL literal value”.